# Django:JSON response and render in function based view

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Im working on django rest framework and using a function based views. Im using 2 functions, one to render html and another for json response. How can I **combine both the function** to have more effecient code

My code

```
def register(request):
    return render(request, 'register.html')

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SignupSerializer(data=request.data)
        print 'ser'
        print serializer
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors,\
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                    'status': 'Created',
                    'message': 'Verification email has been sent to your email. Please verify your account.'
                }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled by your serializer, as described in [part2](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/) of the drf tutorial.

It works like this:

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from your_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blahblah/$', views.create_user),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

## views.py

```
def create_user(request, format=None): # add this format argument
    ...
```

Based on the format argument, you can decide you want to the request to be rendered.